# Converting SCORM 1.2 XML to 2004 with wrapper tool

Tags: scorm

I found a nice wrapper tool to convert SCORM 1.2 api to 2004, however what are the minimum changes needed to XML files in addition?  I assume at least imsmanifest.xml needs updating?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert a SCORM 1.2 manifest to a SCORM 2004 manifest, you will need to make several changes:

1) The XML namespace declarations in the header are different for 2004.
2) You will need to have a specific value in the manifest-level metadata node's schemeversion element. (The value will depend on the SCORM 2004 edition you are using).
3) The case of the "t" in the "adlcp:scormType" attribute on the resource node is capital instead of lowercase.
4) To get the behavior expected by most users (and to replicate the behavior provided by most SCORM 1.2 LMS's), you will need some very basic sequencing information.

There are some good examples at http://www.scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/golf-examples/

See the Simple Single SCO for the differences between 1.2 and 2004 and the Basic Run-Time Calls example for the minimal sequencing information that should be included.

There also used to be an XSLT document for transforming SCORM 1.2 manifest to SCORM 2004 manifests floating around. You might be able to dig that up via a Google search.